# Prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x) - f(x + 1)}{f(x)}\, dx$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

This is one of the problems I got in a test today, and one that i got no idea how to solve.

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be strictly decreasing continuous function with $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$. Prove that $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{f(x) - f(x + 1)}{f(x)}\, dx$$ diverges.

I tries using the fact that $f$ has maximum and minimum on every closed intervals $[0,b]$  then limitting $b\to \infty$, $$\int_0^b \left( 1 - \frac{f(x + 1)}{f(x)}\right) dx  = b - \int_0^b \frac{f(x + 1)}{f(x)} dx \geq b - \int_0^b  f(0)/f_{\min}$$

But the integral on the right doesn't seem to converge as $b\to\infty$.

Any hint?

Comment: You have to prove it diverges .

Comment: If I can show the last integral converge, the integral in question would be diverges since $b$ tend to $\infty$

Comment: It diverges  $\infty-\infty\neq 0$

Comment: $\infty - \infty$ expression might result on convergen.

Comment: When you try to prove something, it might be a god idea to check it on an example first. Take $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x+1}$. This function clearly satisfies the conditions in the question, and the integral in the last line diverges. Thus you can't prove it converges with those assumptions.

Comment: It's Putnam 2010 A6: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h381039p2109513

Comment: Just noticing the fact that $f(x)>0$ and $0 < \dfrac{f(x+1)}{f(x)} <1 $ should be enough as that would mean your integrand is  between 0 and 1 and so diverging

Comment: @LordKK $0<\frac{1}{x^{2}}<1$ for $x>1$. The fact the the integrand is between zero and one doesn't have any effect on the convergence.

Comment: @eranreches  But, how is that a counterexample ?

Comment: @LordKK Just saying that $0<\frac{f\left(x+1\right)}{f\left(x\right)}<1$ is not enough.

Answer (score -5):

(done on my phone)

If $f'$ exists then
$f(x+1)-f(x) \approx f'(x)$
so the integrand is about
$-f'(x)/f(x) = (-\ln(f(x)))'$
so the integral out to $T$
is about $-\ln(f(T))
\to \infty$.

Not sure how to modify this
for general $f$.